# Retrieving particular row just inserted in SQL table

Tags: sql, perl, dbi

I have a table called `BUILD_INFO` and it has the following columns:

- `BUILD_ID`
- `BUILD_NAME`
- `DATE`
- `USER`

The `BUILD_ID` is an autoincrement field, so I don't set it when I do an insert. It's the primary key that is used to relate this row in this table to other rows in other tables.

When I insert a new row in the `BUILD_INFO` table, I want to know the `BUILD_ID` that was set, so I can retrieve it and use it when I add rows in other tables.

I can't really query it by the other columns because other rows could duplicate these column values. I can't simply requery the table and pull up the largest `BUILD_ID` because another user might have inserted a row after I did. It be nice if there was something like a `Row Number` that I could retrieve and query rows by. Does something like that exist?

I'm writing my script in Perl using the `DBI` module and my database could be Oracle or MySql.

How can I retrieve the information of the row I just inserted in SQL or in using the Perl `DBI` module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$dbh->last_insert_id();
```

But see the caveats in http://p3rl.org/DBI#last_insert_id

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you want the [last_insert_id](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBI/DBI.pm#last_insert_id) method on the database handle. But, really, your life would be far easier if you looked at [DBIx::Class](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/) and stopped writing raw SQL.

Comment: I'm reading the documentation but am unclear on where (or if)it specifies the following information. Am I to understand that last_inser_id is specific to my dbHandle? So if I insert a row using it and sleep for 30 seconds during which time N number of rows have been inserted by other dbHandles, when my dbHandle wakes up and goes to fetch its last_insert_id it will have the one that it inserted before it went to sleep?

Comment: Surely that's a simple enough thing to test. Just write a test program with more than one dbh and see what happens to last_insert_id when you insert rows using the different database handles. It looks to me as though the last_insert_id is set and stored as the insertion happens, so it will be correct no matter what has happened on other handles.

Comment: @Dr. Dredel: yes, at least for MySQL; for Oracle, check the documentation for the DBD you are using.

Comment: davorg, Not to pick at nits, but I'd argue that the vast majority of the questions that are asked here are ones that are "easy enough to test".  The whole point is to leverage (and contribute to) the collective knowledge base of your peers who have already written said tests, to save oneself a lot of time and, possibly, stumble (as I just did in this thread) across more elegant solutions to problems that had alternate (less elegant) solutions in my code.  (Thank you, btw, for posting that answer!).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [davorg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7231/davorg) for pointing out the `DBI->last_inserted_row()` method in the `DBI` package. I'm new to the `DBI` package and somehow missed it despite the fact it's clearly listed just two entries above `selectrow_hashref` method in the HTML index. That sounds like what I'm looking for.

As for your concern, I am actually creating a package, so we can get away from writing raw SQL queries. I hate raw SQL queries for a variety of reasons. First of all, they're not exactly easy for most developers to write and they can be tricky to understand. Plus, they're usually hard coded to assumptions of the database layout and how it is connected. Most importantly of all, most developers suck at writing them.

I wish I knew about DBIx before. That would have saved me a lot of work. The problem is that our development machine has no Internet access which makes installing packages a big pain. I have to go through the DBIx documentation. Right now, it looks a bit more complex than what we need.

Thanks too to [ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17389/ysth) for also pointing out the `DBI->last_insert_row()` method too (and the caveats that go with it). Somehow, I missed this method while reading the `DBI` documentation. I'll have to see if it works in Oracle It'll work with MySql because the column we index our table by is an autoincrement column.